# Finding maximum element in a list programmatically in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, max

I have been trying to find the maximum element in a list using a simple program

```
print ("Enter the elements of array seperated by spaces : ")
t = str(raw_input())
arr = list()
arr = map(long,t.split(' '))
print arr
print max(arr)
for i in arr:
    m=arr[0]
    if i>m:
        m=i
print ("The largest element in arary is : "+str(m))
```

The **input** that I passed in was :

**1 2 3 4 5 23682967 4574 433**

And the expected answer for the same should be **23682967**

which is what I'm able to get using the inbuilt function of python called max()

but not from the code that I've written,

The output that my code gives is : **433**

Can someone please guide me in understanding this behavior of python ?

Comment: `m=arr[0]` should be outside the `for` loop

Comment: Anand's answer is great. Nothing to add on that. But I wanted to give three points of feedback on your code. Hopefully you learn something from it. (1) `raw_input` already returns a string, so no need to use `str` on it. (2) `raw_input` supports giving a prompt, so no need to use `print` before. (3) The first assignment of `arr` does nothing, because you reassign it in the next statement. You can just remove that line.

Comment: @agtoever Thanks for these points, All of them noted, they would surely improve my coding skills in future programs. Thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue occurs because of the following line inside your for loop -

```
m=arr[0]
```

It causes `i` to be checked against the first element in the array always causing your loop solution to return the last element that is bigger than the first element in the array which in your case is `433`.

You should have that line before the for loop. Example -

```
m=arr[0]
for i in arr:
    if i>m:
        m=i
```

Comment: Yup, It's working now, Thanks Anand for such a quick and wonderful explanation over the behavior :)